# Как можно ограничить количество введенных символов qtableView?

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно ограничить количество введенных символов в строку "Событие"?

Вот код:

```
model = new QSqlTableModel(this,db);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setTable("TableEventBalancer");
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);

int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
font.setPointSize(12);
ui->tableView->setFont(font);

ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0,QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(1,QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(2,QHeaderView::Stretch);

model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("number"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("ID"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("_date"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Дата"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("text"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Событие"))
```

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вы хотите ограничить количество выводимых символов или количество вводимых, в процессе редактирования таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы выполнить задуманную Вами вещь необходимо перекрыть модель использованную Вами. Ниже привожу пример, ограничения вывода данных 3 символами на примере QStandardItemModel. Ваш конкретный пример, не беру поскольку придется поднимать базу данных (QSqlTableModel).

**Файл customstringmodel.h:**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMSTRINGMODEL_H
#define CUSTOMSTRINGMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class CustomStringModel: public QStandardItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomStringModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    // QAbstractItemModel interface
public:
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
};

#endif // CUSTOMSTRINGMODEL_H
```

**Файл customstringmodel.cpp**

```
#include "customstringmodel.h"

CustomStringModel::CustomStringModel(QObject *parent)
    : QStandardItemModel(parent)
{

}

QVariant CustomStringModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        QString str = QStandardItemModel::data(index, role).toString();
        if (str.size() > 3) {
            str.resize(3);
            str+="...";
        }
        return str;
    }
    else {
        return QStandardItemModel::data(index, role);
    }
}
```

**Использование:** (не обращайте внимание на заполнение модели)

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    CustomStringModel *model = new CustomStringModel(this);
    model->setRowCount(4);
    model->setColumnCount(4);
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row){
        QString test = "";
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; ++col){
            test+= QString::number(row);
            QStandardItem * item = new QStandardItem(test);
            model->setItem(row, col, item);
        }
    }
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

**Ну и сам результат:**

[image: Ну и сам результат]